# ad-invariant skew-symmetric form $\omega(x,y,z)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a lie algebra and $(,)$ a symmetric bilinear ad-invariant form on $\mathfrak{g}$, and define $\omega(x,y,z) = ([x,y],z)$, for $x,y,z \in \mathfrak{g}$. Show that $\omega$ is skew-symmetric and ad-invariant. For ad-invariance, I note that $\omega(ad(x),ad(y),ad(z)) = ([ad(x),ad(y)],ad(z)) = (ad[x,y],ad(z)) = ([x,y],z)= \omega(x,y,z)$, showing ad-invariance because $(,)$ is ad-invariant. How do I show skew-symmetry? I am not sure what I even have to show. I know a skew-symmetric bilinear form is one that satisfies $(x,y) = -(y,x)$, but what is meant in this context?

Comment: The question is, what is meant by skew-symmetric in this context?

Comment: Skew-symmetry should mean that interchanging any two of the inputs negates the output, or that (equivalently) any permutation of the inputs multiplies the output by the sign of the permutation. It is enough to show that $\omega(x, y, z) = -\omega(y, x, z) = -\omega(x, z, y)$ since the transpositions $(12)$ and $(23)$ generate the symmetric group.

Comment: I know $\omega(x,y,z) = -\omega(y,x,z)$, because $[x,y] = -[y,x]$. Would you know how to show $\omega(x,y,z) = -\omega(x,z,y)$? Considering we have to show $([x,y],z) = -([x,z],y)$, but does this follow from some jacobi identity? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you use the ad-invariance to move the $[x,-]$ over and then use symmetry to move the bracket over